# calfem toolbox MATLAB - displacements not showing on graph

Tags: matlab

You have to have the calfem toolbox to be able to run this code, so I'm hoping some people do!

I've written some code to try and show the displacements, from applied `udls`, and I've used 
    uu = extract(Edof,UU);

but they aren't showing on my figure, can anyone figure out why?

```
addpath ([cd, '/fem']);

% Constants
E  = 180e9; 
AB = 39.7e2; IB = 4413e4; 
AC = 110e2;  IC = 9449e4;
q1 = -15e3;  w1 = -10e3; w2 = 5e3;

LX1 = 5; LX2 = 10; LX3 = 15; LX4 = 20; 
LY1 = 5; LY2 = 8;  LY3 = 9;

% Specify Node Coordinates
nodes = [  0,   0;
           0, LY1;
         LX1, LY2;
         LX2, LY1;
         LX2, LY3;
         LX3, LY2;
         LX4, LY1;
         LX4, 0];

% Specify Elements Nodes
conn = [1,2;
        2,3;
        2,4;
        3,4;
        3,5;
        4,5;
        4,6;
        4,7;
        5,6;
        6,7;
        7,8];

Nelem = length(conn);

% Initialise Structural Force/Stiffness Matrices
KK = zeros(8*3);
FF = zeros(8*3,1);

% Define Column and Beam Properties
Cprop = [E, AC, IC];
Bprop = [E, AB, IB];

% Initialise system properties
Edof  = zeros(Nelem, 1+6);
Ex    = zeros(Nelem, 2);
Ey    = zeros(Nelem, 2);
Eq    = zeros(Nelem, 2);
Eprop = zeros(Nelem,3);

for ii = 1:Nelem
    % Look up nodes of element
    node1 = conn(ii,1); node2 = conn(ii,2);

    % Work out dof based on node number
    dof1 = node1*3 + [-2,-1,0];
    dof2 = node2*3 + [-2,-1,0];

    % Assign to Edof
    Edof(ii,:) = [ii, dof1, dof2];

    % Look up coordinate based on node
    x1 = nodes(node1,1); y1=nodes(node1,2);
    x2 = nodes(node2,1); y2=nodes(node2,2);

    % Assign to Ex and Ey
    Ex(ii,:) = [x1,x2];
    Ey(ii,:) = [y1,y2];

    % Decide if the element is column or not
    if ii==1||11;
        Eprop(ii,:) = Cprop;
    elseif ii==2;
        Eprop(ii,:) = Bprop;
        Eq(ii,:) = [0.515*w1, 0.857*w1];
    elseif ii==5;
        Eprop(ii,:) = Bprop;
        Eq(ii,:) = [0.196*w1, 0.98*w1];  
    elseif ii==3||8;
        Eprop(ii,:) = Bprop;
        Eq(ii,:) = [0, q1];   
    elseif ii==9;
        Eprop(ii,:) = Bprop;
        Eq(ii,:) = [0.196*w2, 0.98*w2];
    elseif ii==10;
        Eprop(ii,:) = Bprop;
        Eq(ii,:) = [0.515*w1, 0.857*w1]; 
    else
        Eprop(ii,:) = Bprop;
    end

    % assemble system
    [KE,FE] = beam2e(Ex(ii,:), Ey(ii,:), Eprop(ii,:), Eq(ii,:));
    % Combine structural Stiffness forces
    [KK,FF] = assem(Edof(ii,:), KK, KE, FF,FE);
end

% Apply Boundary Conditions
bc = [1,0; 2,0; 3,0; 22,0; 23,0; 24,0];

% Solve System
[UU,RR] = solveq(KK,FF,bc);

figure(1)
% Undisplaced Shape
eldraw2(Ex,Ey,[1,1,1])
% Extract Local Displacements
uu = extract(Edof,UU);

% Plot Displaced Shape
scale = 1e2;
eldisp2(Ex,Ey, uu, [1,2,1], scale);

% Add Scale Bar for 10mm
pltscalb2(scale,[1e-2,6,6],[2]);

% Tidy up Graph
axis([-2,22,0,10])
axis equal
xlabel('X, m'); ylabel('Y, m')
title('Simple Portal Frame - Displacement')
```

Comment: While going over your code to do some basic cleanup, I noticed you wrote `if i==1||11`. You know that this will *always* evaluate to `true`, right? In other words, the other cases cannot be reached...You'll have to write `if i==8 || i==11`, similar for the other cases.

Comment: thank you,for information we realised initial conditions were incorrect!

Comment: Your problem is resolved then?